# Example in the theory of quotient maps - the composition is a quotient map, but the first map is not

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

If $f:X \to Y$ and $g:Y \to X$ are continuous functions, it is well known that:

- If both of them are quotient maps, then the composition $g \circ f$ is a quotient map; and
- If $g \circ f$ is a quotient map, then $g$ is a quotient map.

However, there is no need of $f$ being a quotient map if we take $g \circ f$ to be a quotient map (even if we assume that $f$ is surjective); this is remarked (without the presentation of an example, and regarded as a fact of easy verification) at Engelking's book.

Indeed, after some reasoning I came out with a whole class of examples: for any $f:X \to Y$ which is surjective and continuous but does not coinduce the topology of $Y$, let $Z$ be a singleton and $g:Y \to Z$ the only possible function in this context - and here you go, the composition is a quotient map but $f$ is not.

I was thinking, are there more nicer examples ? In particular, I would like to see examples where $Z$ is an infinite metric space, a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, or something like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've been reading this part of the book and I post what I've come up with here that fits OP's requirements. Let $X=[0,1]$ and let $Z=\mathbb S^1$ which is a subspace of $\mathbb C\cong\mathbb R^2$. Take a point $1'\notin\mathbb S^1$ and let $Y=\mathbb S^1\cup\{1'\}$ be the topological space whose open sets are the sets that are of the form
$$\tilde U=
\begin{cases}
U&1\not\in U\\
U\cup\{1'\}&1\in U
\end{cases}
$$
for some usual open sets $U$ in $\mathbb S^1$. Finally, let the map $f\colon X\to Y$ and $g\colon Y\to Z$ be defined by
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
e^{2\pi ix}&x\in[0,1)\\
1'&x=1
\end{cases}
\text{ and }g(y)=
\begin{cases}
y&y\in\mathbb S^1\\
1&y=1'
\end{cases}.
$$
It can be verified that both $f,g$ are continuous surjections, that $g\circ f$ is the quotient map $x\mapsto e^{2\pi ix}$, and that $f$ is not a quotient map (if it is, $f$ would be a homeomorphism since it is bijective, which is impossible since $X$ does not have an indistinguishable pair of points).